# Association cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, cakephp-2.3

I have a `projects` table which reference all the projects that I have, and an `accesses` table, which should associate all accesses (ftp informations, hoster, pma) for each project.

My table `accesses` looks like this, with `project_id` that combines this accesses to the id field for a project of my `projects` table:

http://puu.sh/aKXH7/32489f5825.png

So, I've an action view in my controller `ProjectsController.php` with an id in parameter that will allow me to see these accesses according to the project that I selected.
I placed in my model Project.php :

```
public $hasOne = array('Access');
```

But when I do :

```
$projects = $this->Project->Access->find('all');
```

I just recover the data of my table `accesses`.

Should I use a contain with my association, or did I make a mistake somewhere ?

I have a little trouble with these associations in cakephp.

If you have an idea to do what I want, don't hesitate.

Thank you for your help.

Etix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with cakePHP [**recursive**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive) functionality like following

```
$this->Project->recursive = 1;
$projects = $this->Project->find('all');
```

Comment: I'd been in the habit to putting my recursivity to -1 in my AppModel, but actually that works well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try define

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Project' => array(
        'className' => 'Project',
        'foreignKey' => 'project_id'
    )
);
```

in your Access Model

Comment: I don't really need an Access Model.

I solved my problem differently.

Either I put a recursivity to 1 like Sadikhasan said or I can simply do this :

    `$projects = $this->Project->find('all', array( 'contain' => 'Access', 'conditions' => array('Project.id' => $id)));`

because I have a recursivity to -1 in my AppModel.

Thank you for guiding me !